# Unable to signup user from custom mobile App

Tags: odoo, customization, odoo-14

Please guide.

Creating a new mobile app, not able to signup! Returns some error while tryting to call /web/signup and also while directly calling res.users create as sudo.

Please see the error message

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception) File
> "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 316, in _handle_exception raise
> exception.with_traceback(None) from
> new_causepsycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist:
> integer = booleanLINE 6: AND (p.company_id=false OR p.company_id ...

Seems this error raised from _get_multi function in ir_property.py

Thanks in advance

I use a custom controller for receiving request from mobile app and tries to call Odoo Core signup (do_signup located in auth_signup/controller/main) function. It reaches up to there and exceution moves to ir_property and returns error as mentioned.
Please see the sample code which try to use

```
user = {
        'name' : user_info['name'],
        'phone': user_info['phone'],
        'email': 'test@example.com',#user_info['email'] ,
        'login': user_info['phone'],
        'password': password,
        'confirm_password':  password,
    }

    user_info = AuthSignupHome().do_signup(user)
```

Comment: Can you show how you call the API? Is there customization in the Odoo part?

Comment: Please see the updated post

Answer (score 0):

But `/web/signup` it's a website service `type='http'`. You need a controller `type='json'` for call it from your custom mobile app.

I hope this answer can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, actually I am not calling it directly. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Please complete the stacktrace error for more details.